# How to optionally redirect to a payment page after adding a node?

Tags: 7, commerce, redirection

I want to add an option to the node add form so that the user who creates the node can choose if the node will be " promoted " or not. If the promoted option is selected, then I want to redirect the user to a payment page, so that the option charges can be payed.

Any suggestions about how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1a: Optional redirect to payment page

Add a Boolean field to each content type for which you want to offer such "Promoted" option, say its allowed options are `Yes` or `No`.

Then use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module like so:

- **Event**: After saving a node
- **Condition**: (both conditions must be true)

  1. Entity has field "Promoted"
  2. Data Comparison "Promoted" = "Yes"
- **Action**: Perform a page Redirect to your Payment Page

## Step 1b: Limit node access while payment is not completed

To wait for the payment to be completed (and not "submit" the node yet), you could use the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module, and the Content Access Rules Integrations module.

So that "After saving content" (= Event), you "Give 'authenticated user' the permission to 'view own content' for the specific node" (= Action). This additional "Action" can be added is a 2nd action to the same rumle suggested above.

This would be a variation of what is explained in [this article](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/content-access/) also (within "Access Control Customized for Your Needs").

## Step 2: Promote the node (after payment)

After the payment is received, you could use that "Event" to trigger another rule, which basically consists of these actions:

- Mark the node as "Promoted".
- Remove the node access restriction, so that all appropriate roles can view the node.

## Step 3: Stop the promotion of the node

If at some point in the future the "Promoted" node no longer should be promoted, then you could use the Rules Scheduler ( a sub-module of the Rules scheduler) to trigger a rule to no longer mark the node as "Promoted.

**Note**: If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), the checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).

Comment: thank you so much, but i want not to submit the node till the payment is made

Comment: I updated my answer as per your most recent comment to my answer. Does this help?